# What are the UI components for hierarchical display in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Tree view is probably the most well known representation in Windows desktop for hierarchical items display.  What would be the equivalent UI component in Android phone if not for any mobile phone platform?

Comment: You want to view your layout views hierarchy in android studio?

Comment: Yes, and I thought tree view style is not a good fit for the small screen with nature of phone how it is held in hand which makes sliding gesture more natural with one hand maneuver than using both hands for click.  I could not find standard UI control recommended from Android which has equivalent display functioning of tree view in hierarchical items display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Expandable listview` for ur tree structure.

**ExpandableListView**

A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling two-level list. This differs from the `ListView` by allowing two levels. Groups which can individually be expanded to show its children. The items come from the `ExpandableListAdapter` associated with this view.

[image]

For more complex structure you can use

Here is a [Multilevel Expandable listview](http://www.androidcodec.com/android-expandablelistview-multi-level/)

you can also use third party library for your tree structure.

[Android Tree View](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView)

Comment: I liked the idea of expanding the ExpandableListView although I was hoping more standardized way than customization.  I guess this is the closest we can get with industry allowed standard.  Can you please add link to the text Multilevel Expandable ListView instead of "example"?  That would be neat.